# C program, strlen not counting whitespace?

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings, fgets, strlen

i've written a simple program, where the program takes and imput and prints out the characters in sequence and counts them

```
char name[100];
int counter=0
printf("Enter name and surname:");
scanf("%s",&name);
    
for(int i=0; i<(strlen(name)); i++){
        printf("%c \n",name[i]);
        counter++;
printf("%d",counter)
```

for some reason , when i imput John Snow, it prints out only

```
J
o
h
n 
4
```

desired output

```
J
o
h
n

S
n
o
w
10
```

any help please? within reasonable skill level :D if posible no malloc() free() and memory things, its supposed to be quite easy :D

Comment: `%s` only reads one word. There can't be whitespace in it.

Comment: BTW, get rid of `&` before `name`. Arrays automatically decay to pointers when used as function arguments.

Comment: oh dam.... how could i fix it to read with whitespace?

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a whole line of input.

Comment: You could read a whole line instead, using e.g. `fgets`. But then you might want to read [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) as well.

Comment: so fgets(name) and it should be ok?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`getline()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) instead

Comment: Just remember to remove the newline at the end. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Comment: tried with fgets() does the same thing

Comment: BTW, `strlen()` does count white-spaces.  It is just that `name[]` does not contain any white-space.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you have to write

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%s",&name);
```

Secondly when the format string `"%s"` is used the function stops to enter characters as soon as a white space character is encountered.

You should write instead

```
scanf( " %99[^\n]", name );
```

Another approach is to use the function `fgets`

```
fgets( name, sizeof( name ), stdin );
```

The function can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string. To remove it you can write

```
name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Comment: when i put scanf( "%99[^\n]", name ); it automaticly skips imput, doesnt let me enter anything

Comment: @D.K. See the blank before the symbol % in the format string.